# Where do I learn polymer material design with complete documentation and examples?

Tags: javascript, cordova, polymer, material-design, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to update a Phonegapp app for android using polymer material design. Can someone please help me out in finding some good documentation, tutorials and startup guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google's Material Design sight: http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

This is "Google Material" https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/
From here you can either view the Github or just download the whole thing. 
I doubt there is much in the way of Tutorials, you'll have to just read through the Documentation (https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html)